# Geocortex Essentials

Tags: arcgis-server, map-service, geocortex

I am currently using Geocortex Essentials REST elements and I am in the process of adding a new map service. I've entered in my url to the map service's in ArcGIS Server, but can't see my newly created map service in the dropdown list. Any ideas or hints as to why my map service isn't appearing?

Comment: Your version of essentials would make small differences to the answer. Generally geocortex should find all services when you input arc server url. NOTE: you want to input your web adaptor url.

Answer (score 3):

Once you configure Geocortex Essentials using post installation manager (to work with ArcGIS Server) , open Geocortex Essentials Manager. And in Map - click on Add Map Service.

Here you can enter keyword to search your map service which is published in ArcGIS Server. You can limit your search within your ArcGIS Server portal. Here you can get list of all map services published and then you can add them directly to Geocortex Essentials.